# drag and drop more than 2 images using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

How do I drag and drop more than 2 images using HTML and JS, I have 4 divs and 4 images, and everytime I drag and drop more than 2 the first img gets put back in its original place, not more than 2 images can be dragged to the divs, am I making any sense?
here's my HTML:

```js
    function allowDrop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
    }
    
    function drag(ev) {
        ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    }
    
    function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    }
```

```html
<p>على عكس الحزازيات والسرخسيات، لا تُكوِّن الجراثيم نباتات مشيجية، بل تنتج مباشرة<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>  أو <div id="div2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div><br><br>
                            يتمّ التلقيح في <div id="div3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> حين تُطلِق <div id="div4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div> الذكرية أعدادًا كبيرة من حبوب اللقاح التي تنتقل في الهواء.
                            <br><img id="drag1" src="Images/first-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48">
                            <img id="drag2" src="Images/second-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48">
                            <img id="drag2" src="Images/third-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48">
                            <img id="drag2" src="Images/forth-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your img ids

```
<br><img id="drag1" src="Images/first-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48">
                            <img id="drag2" src="Images/second-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48">
                            <img id="drag3" src="Images/third-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48">
                            <img id="drag4" src="Images/forth-ans.png" draggable="true"
                            ondragstart="drag(event)" height="48"></p>
```

To find this kind of problems you should learn how to use debug